# When inspecting page elements/network for an JS interactive graph, where would you find all the chart data for this website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Am trying to extract all the data from these charts found here: https://www.eurocontrol.int/Economics/DailyTrafficVariation-States.html

I am trying to get as much data from here as possible but not sure where it is in the page elements/network. I think usually the interactive charts data are stored in .json or .csv but I am not seeing any of that here.

I want to be able to get the data that appears when one hovers over the gray bars in the first table where it says "% vs 2019(daily): __ ".

Also any ways to do this through python is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be located inside this link:
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
or this link: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js ,

It also might be stored on a server

Other than that I am not too sure.